# Mock a network call made by child process in Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking, child-process

I am writing a jest test in which I have to spawn a child process. That child process, during its execution, makes a GET call to an api using "request" module. I want to mock the response of that call.

So far I have tried

1. Mocking request module using jest.mock
2. Used nock
3. Used mitm module

But nothing seems to work. The call is always going to actual api. In other tests, where the call is made by main process itself, a simple jest.mock of request module does the trick but not here when the child process is making the call.

Someone please provide some suggestions on how to mock the network call made by a child process in jest nodejs.

Comment: This is not good approach, test child process in isolation , do not try to mock it from another process, this would not working.

Comment: The issue is that I want to test something that is triggered with a cli command and I think that's possible only if a spawn a child to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock a function called by child process in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76651488/mock-a-function-called-by-child-process-in-jest)